# Display current date and time without punctuation

Tags: bash, shell, date

For example, I want to display current date and time as the following format:

```
yyyymmddhhmmss
```

How do I do that? It seems like most date format comes with `-`, `/`, `:`, etc.

Answer (score 204, accepted):

Here you go:

```
date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S
```

As `man date` says near the top, you can use the `date` command like this:

> ```
> date [OPTION]... [+FORMAT]
> ```

That is, you can give it a format parameter, starting with a `+`. 
You can probably guess the meaning of the formatting symbols I used:

- `%Y` is for year
- `%m` is for month
- `%d` is for day
- ... and so on

You can find this, and other formatting symbols in `man date`.

Answer (score 42):

A simple example in shell script

```
#!/bin/bash

current_date_time="`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`";
echo $current_date_time;
```

With out punctuation format :- +%Y%m%d%H%M%S
With punctuation :-            +%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S

Comment: `"\`date +%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\`"` gives me a `date: illegal time format`

Answer (score 16):

**Without punctuation** (as @Burusothman has mentioned):

```
current_date_time="`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`";
echo $current_date_time;
```

O/P:

```
20170115072120
```

---

**With punctuation**:

```
current_date_time="`date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`";
echo $current_date_time;
```

O/P:

```
2017-01-15 07:25:33
```

Answer (score 7):

If you're using Bash you could also use one of the following commands:

```
printf '%(%Y%m%d%H%M%S)T'       # prints the current time
printf '%(%Y%m%d%H%M%S)T' -1    # same as above
printf '%(%Y%m%d%H%M%S)T' -2    # prints the time the shell was invoked
```

You can use the Option `-v varname` to store the result in `$varname` instead of printing it to stdout:

```
printf -v varname '%(%Y%m%d%H%M%S)T'
```

While the date command will always be executed in a subshell (i.e. in a separate process) printf is a builtin command and will therefore be faster.

Comment: For anyone looking for further documentation on what `%` options you can pass in, this seems to be using the `date` command. So, `man date` will give you the available options.

Answer (score 0):

*Interesting/funny* way to do this using [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) (requires `bash 4.4` or newer):

> **`${parameter@operator} - P operator`**
>
> The expansion is a string that is the result of expanding the value of parameter as if it were a prompt string.

```
$ show_time() { local format='\D{%Y%m%d%H%M%S}'; echo "${format@P}"; }
$ show_time
20180724003251
```